# An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Failed to locate opened application window with appId

Tags: azure, selenium, azure-web-app-service, appium, winappdriver

Class Initialization method xxxxx.Features.PublicAppFeature.FeatureSetup threw exception. OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Failed to locate opened application window with appId: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, and processId: xxxx.

An Application opened on the Remote machine. But they failed with the above error.

1. Run on Azure Pipeline on a Self-hosted machine(Window Server 2019 Datacenter)
2. Application is opened on the machine.
   AppiumOptions options = new AppiumOptions();
   options.AddAdditionalCapability("app", AppPath);
   options.AddAdditionalCapability("ms:waitForAppLaunch", $"{SecondsToWaitOnOpen}");
   options.AddAdditionalCapability("ms:experimental-webdriver", false);
   session = new WindowsDriver(WindowsApplicationDriverUrl, options);

Comment: Please include more information about which steps you took to get where you are now and your OS, the remote OS, etc.

Comment: @NoahMay I am able to open the UWP application on a Remote machine using Appium Option then after it failed to run further automation.